# Understanding MATLAB code for creating a wireless sensor network

Tags: matlab

I have the following MATLAB code that is used to aid in creating a wireless sensor network:

```
for i=1:n
    S(i).xb=rand*0.5*xm;
    S(i).yb=rand*0.5*ym;
    S(i).E=Eo;
    S(i).G=0;
    S(i).type='N';
    S(i).id=i;
    S(i).D=dist(BS.x,BS.y,S(i).xb,S(i).yb);
    S(i).Etx=Eelec*k+Eamp*k*S(i).D^2;
    plot(S(i).xb,S(i).yb,'o');    
end
plot(BS.x,BS.y,'rx');
```

---

In this program, why are there dots in the code? For example, `S(i).xb=rand*0.5*xm;`.  Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Looks like xb is a member variable of some object S(i)

Answer (score 1):

In this code, `S` will be an array of structures.  Each structure will contain the following member variables:

- `xb`
- `yb`
- `E`
- `G`
- `type`
- `id`
- `D`
- `Etx`

Doing `S(i).xb = rand*0.5*xm;` will first create a structure within the array `S` at location `i` that contains a single member `xb`.  This will be assigned the value of `rand*0.5*xm`.  The rest of the statements will keep appending more variables to the same structure at location `i` in the array.

After, if you wish to access the member variable at location `i` for the array `S`, you would still do `S(i).xb`, or `S(i).yb`, etc.

Essentially, you can think of `S` as having an array of elements where each element has 8 fields within the element.  You'd access a field by using the `.`.